# SQL join maybe. One to one to many

Tags: sql, database, join

I have three sql tables fname, lname, and children:

```
fname(id INT, fname TEXT)

lname(id INT, lname TEXT, childid INT)

children( childid INT, Name)
```

I would like to to be able to query and see an output like so:

```
John Doe Jane
John Doe Cynthia
May Jane Paul
Mary Jane Peter
Jimmy Smith Chris
```

Where John comes from fname and Doe comes from lname based on the ID field.  Then I want all his children based on the childid field.  Same for other folks as well.

Thanks,

Comment: How about grandparents? Parents have parents, too!

Comment: I would really advise against putting first name and last name in separate tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT fn.fname, ln.lname, c.Name
FROM fname fn
JOIN lname ln ON ln.id = fn.id
LEFT JOIN children c ON c.childid = ln.childid
```

However, I think you should rethink your design.

I would think about something like that:

```
Person (id INT, fname TEXT, lname TEXT, parentId INT NULL);
```

With that, your query should look like that:

```
SELECT p.fname, p.lname, c.fname
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Person c ON c.parentId = p.Id
WHERE p.parentId = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(`fname`.`fname`, `lname`.`lname`, `children`.`name`)        
FROM `fname`
INNER JOIN `lname`
    ON `fname`.`id` = `lname`.`id`
INNER JOIN `children`
    ON `lname`.`childid` = `children`.`childid`
```